# ConditionalOnBean with RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am creating a bean conditionally in my configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.acme.foo.bar")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Conditional(ShouldCreateBean.class)
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    }

}
```

I have a rest controller that only should get created if `MyBean` is created

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("endpoint")
@ConditionalOnBean(MyBean.class)
public class ArmController {}
```

Unfortunately, the rest controller does not get created. It seems that the conditional on the controller is executed before my bean is created.

Is there a way to create the controller after `MyBean` is created? Some sort of ordering in conditionals?

Comment: What about using the `@DependsOn` annotation?

Comment: You may find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518696/spring-boot-conditionalonbean-annotation

Comment: `@DependsOn` won't help here. It controls the order in which beans are created while `@ConditionalOnBean` and `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` relies on the order in which beans are defined.

Comment: I noticed that @AndyWilkinson has updated the answer few minutes ago, look at it again if you've already seen it.